# Difference in hand color between pretrain dataset and fine dataset?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

I have a pose estimation model pretrained on a dataset in which hands are in its nartural color. I want to finetune that model on the dataset of hands of surgeons doing surgeries. Those hands are in surgical gloves so the image of the hands are a bit different than normal hands.

[pretraine image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsW8G.jpg)

[finetune image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK5KL.jpg)

Does this difference in hand colors affect the model performance?
If I can make images of those surgical hands more like normal hands, will I get better performance?

Comment: better ask this on the AI/ML/data science stack exchanges. this one's focus is on programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on what your pre-trained model has learned to capture from the pre-training (initial) dataset. Suppose your model had many feature maps and not enough skin color variation in your pre-training dataset (leads to overfitting issues). In that case, your model has likely "taken the path of least resistance" and exploited that to learn feature maps that rely on the color space as means of feature extraction (which might not generalize well due to color differences).

The more your pre-training dataset match/overlap with your target dataset, the better the effects of transfer learning will be. So yes, there is a very high chance that making your target dataset (surgical hands) look more similar to your pre-training dataset will positively impact your model's performance. Moreover, I would conjecture that introducing some color variation (e.g., Color Jitter augmentation) in your pre-training dataset could also help your model generalize to your target dataset.

Comment: Right now I'm just thinking of 1 solution to map color of target dataset to pre-training dataset, which is adding/subtracting values from RGB channels and visually check that if the target images look simlar to pre-training images or not. 
Is this the correct way to overlap colors between datasets?.
Can you suggest some keywords on how to do this correctly?

Comment: @QuangĐạiNguyễn Hey that could be one way, but a tedious one. I would suggest applying some random color transformations like `ColorJitter` and the likes of it. Also, if time is not a concern and you're mostly worried about the overall performance (generalization), then you could apply "offline augmentation" techniques on your target dataset, while applying "online augmentation" techniques on your pre-training dataset. Check out "albumentations" on google.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you very much! Have a nice day!!!

Comment: @QuangĐạiNguyễn Thanks! You too.